# Wildcard "use" binding works in sequence expression, but not otherwise

Tags: f#

Using the wildcard pattern with `use` works within a sequence expression, but not otherwise. Is there a reason for  this?

```
let mkDisposable() = 
  { new IDisposable with 
      member __.Dispose() = () }

let mkSeq() =  
  seq {
    use _ = mkDisposable() //OK
    ()
  }

let f() =  
  use _ = mkDisposable() //ERROR: 'use' bindings must be of the form 'use <var> = <expr>'
  ()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that this is a natural (but unexpected) consequence of the desugaring of computation expressions (a sequence expression in this case, but this behavior applies to all computation expressions).  [As the spec indicates](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597448),

```
use pat = expr
cexpr
```

is translated to

```
Using(expr, fun pat -> cepxr)
```

Because this is a shallow syntactic translation, you can use any pattern that could be used when writing a function, including just `_`.  However, for normal `use` bindings, the left hand side of the binding must be an *identifier*, not a *pattern* (see [section 6.6.3 of the spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597481)).

Answer (score 1):

I've done a bit of digging and it seems that the special way `seq` expressions are handled changes the rules of `use`. The `seq` expression is in fact transformed into the following with an `IDisposable` field that is disposed upon completion of the sequence.

```
internal sealed class mkSeq@11<a> : GeneratedSequenceBase<a>
{
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never), CompilerGenerated, DebuggerNonUserCode]
    public IDisposable matchValue = matchValue;
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never), CompilerGenerated, DebuggerNonUserCode]
    public int pc = pc;
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never), CompilerGenerated, DebuggerNonUserCode]
    public a current = current;
    public mkSeq@11(IDisposable matchValue, int pc, a current)
    {
    }
    public override int GenerateNext(ref IEnumerable<a> next)
    {
        switch (this.pc)
        {
            case 2:
            {
                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                goto IL_55;
            }
            default:
            {
                this.matchValue = Program.mkDisposable();
                this.pc = 2;
                break;
            }
        }
        this.pc = 3;
        LanguagePrimitives.IntrinsicFunctions.Dispose<IDisposable>(this.matchValue);
        this.matchValue = null;
        this.pc = 3;
        IL_55:
        this.current = default(a);
        return 0;
    }
    public override void Close()
    {
        switch (this.pc)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                goto IL_41;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                goto IL_41;
            }
        }
        this.pc = 3;
        LanguagePrimitives.IntrinsicFunctions.Dispose<IDisposable>(this.matchValue);
        IL_41:
        this.pc = 3;
        this.current = default(a);
    }
    public override bool get_CheckClose()
    {
        switch (this.pc)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                return false;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    [CompilerGenerated, DebuggerNonUserCode]
    public override a get_LastGenerated()
    {
        return this.current;
    }
    [CompilerGenerated, DebuggerNonUserCode]
    public override IEnumerator<a> GetFreshEnumerator()
    {
        return new Program<a>.mkSeq@11(null, 0, default(a));
    }
}
```

Normally `use` is transformed into this:

```
IDisposable e = Program.mkDisposable();
try
{
}
finally
{
    IDisposable disposable = e as IDisposable;
    if (disposable != null)
    {
        disposable.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Without a variable name the compiler will ignore the result of the expression and thus it cannot be disposed. To be honest it seems like a special case should be made for `use` so all the boilerplate is created behind the scenes like we see in `seq` expressions.

Comment: Thanks for doing the research. This seems like a bug. I haven't found anything in the spec about this limitation. Furthermore, the asymmetry is unexpected.